# Шаблон для tuple

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++14

У меня есть нечто такое

```
using size_win = std::tuple<int, int, int, int>;

static void SetSize(int, int, int, int);

void GlWindow::SetSize(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    Size = { a,b,c,d };
}
```

И я хочу заменить функцию SetSize() на шаблонную SetParam()

```
template<typename Param, typename... Type>
static void SetParam(Param&, Type&...);

template<typename Param, typename... Type>
void SetParam(Param &p, Type&... t)
{  
    std::get<i>(p) = { t, ... };
}

SetParam(Size, 200, 200, 800, 600);
```

Но не могу понять как это сделать - в таком виде она не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Тут можно обойтись без рекурсии:

```
template <typename Tuple, typename ...P> void SetParam(Tuple &t, P &&... p)
{
    t = {std::forward<P>(p)...};
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. У меня получилось немного по другому. 

template<typename Param, typename... Type>
  void mUses::SetParam(Param& p, Type... t)
  {  
    p = { t... };
  }

Comment: @WladWlad Такая запись бесспорно короче, но с perfect forwarding (как в ответе) должно быть быстрее.